# Dialog box close after click is made

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have a dialog box open to set photo as profile avatar picture,... how can I close dialog box after click is made? thanks in advance,...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#profile_picture_dialog_<?php echo $profile['User']['id'] ?> a').each(function() {
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href'))
            .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            title: 'Set Profile Picture'
            });

        $link.click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');

            return false;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and here is the dialog box content: (speculation)

```
  a href="/photos/ajax_set_buddy/148" Photo Image Here "/a"
```

Comment: use `.dialog('close');` [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $link.click(function() {
        $dialog.dialog('open');

        $("#the-element-you-want-me-to-click").one("click", function() {
            $dialog.dialog('close');
        });

        return false;
    });
```